# The Timer function freezes the Application window

Tags: c#, timer, delay

Following is my Timer code for 100ms delay :

```
public System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

public void SetTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1); // 1ms
    aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    aTimer.AutoReset = true;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

public void OnTimedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ms_count++;
}

public void delay_ms(UInt32 msPeriod)
{
    ms_count = 0;
    while(ms_count < msPeriod);
}
```

I call it from this function :

```
void PASECVGet(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!SCP.IsOpen) {
        MessageBox.Show("Open the Serial Port");
    } else {
        dataout = "get pase cv";
        delay_ms(100);
        SCP.Write(dataout + "\r");
        blGetPASECV = true;
    }
}
```

I am not able to find a specific reason what is allowing my GUI to freeze. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you think `while(ms_count < msPeriod);` does?

Comment: waits until the condition is true... until ms_count reaches to the value of msPeriod

Comment: that while blocks your thread.

Comment: I am trying to make  a handler which stores the incoming instructions keep them in buffer and then execute them after every 100ms .

Comment: I'd suggest looking at using a `BlockingCollection`. And using `Thread.Sleep` or `Task.Wait`.

Comment: @mjwills It wont work in long run and besides Thread.Sleep also freezes my application

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your current approach. Additionally, please provide a [mcve] of your `BlockingCollection` attempt.

Comment: So, if there is an array of string with 10 commands waiting to be sent on the Serial port and I simply add Thread.sleep after each command sent. It won't freeze my application??
I will try this approach one more time, I will let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Your while block is literally hammering one of your CPUs (are we there yet? are we there yet? are we there yet? are we there yet? are we there yet?). I don't understand your problem fully but I can tell you this - almost **any** solution you choose will be better than the one you have chosen.

Comment: What is wrong with setting the timer to trigger every 100ms & in the timer event send the commands to the serial port if there are any?

Answer (score 2):

The modern way to write this would be:

```
async void PASECVGet(object sender, EventArgs e) //Ugh, async void, but events!
{
    if (!SCP.IsOpen) {
        MessageBox.Show("Open the Serial Port");
    } else {
        dataout = "get pase cv";
        await Task.Delay(100);
        SCP.Write(dataout + "\r");
        blGetPASECV = true;
    }
}
```

Then throw away the rest of your existing code. There's a lot of facilities in C# these days that allow you to focus on *the job to be done*. The era of manually creating timers, threads, etc is starting to fade (hopefully)

I am also worried about `blGetPASECV` above, because a) it seems to be using systems hungarian naming and b) it seems to be for tracking a current *state*. If you have states, it'd be more normal to model that using a single enum and field, not multiple independent booleans.